# I can't load a specific URL using WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I can't load this specific url (http://sia.bogota.unal.edu.co/academia/) using WebView, but I can load other URLs. (See images below)

[image: I can load url using WebViw]

[image: I cant load url using WebView]

This is my code

Activity Class:

```
package co.luisfer.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Activity activity;
    private ProgressDialog progDailog;
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        activity = this;
        progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Please wait...", true);
        progDailog.setCancelable(false);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        settings.setSupportZoom(false);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://sia.bogota.unal.edu.co/academia");
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            progDailog.show();
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            progDailog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't have any clue what's going on.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

PS:  I have already set up the internet permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "can't load" means.

Comment: I have added 2 screenshots, take a look.